# Maintain a sequence of numbers separated by semicolon and perform add, remove operation

Tags: c#, logic

Suppose I have a sequence of no's like:-

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
```

Now I wanted to remove some no's say `(3, 6, 7)` so the sequence would come like:-

```
1;2;4;5;8;9
```

Now If I add the removed no's again say `(3, 6)` then this will give me the sequence like :-

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;8;9 // 7 is not here
```

Comment: Please show your data as valid C# code so that we can see what we're dealing with. Right now it's not clear if this is a string or a sequence of integers.

Comment: Why would you want to use a string instead of using a `List<int>` for such a thing?

Comment: More that a `List<int>`, a `SortedSet<>` would be better.

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Show what you´ve tried and where *specifically* you´ve got problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn `string` into `IEnumerable<T>` and use *Linq*; finally turn the sequence back into `string` with a help of `Join`:

```
  string source = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9";

  int[] exclude = new int[] {3, 6, 7};
  int[] include = new int[] {3, 6};

  var seq = source
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))        // now we have IEnumerable<int>
    .Where(item => !exclude.Contains(item)) // removing "exclude"
    .Concat(include)                        // appending "include"
    .OrderBy(item => item);

  string result = string.Join(";", seq);    // back to string
```

**Edit:** In case you are working with *sets* (no duplicates) you can try `HashSet<T>` e.g.

```
  string source = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9";

  int[] exclude = new int[] { 3, 6, 7 };
  int[] include = new int[] { 3, 6 };

  HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(source
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item)));

  hs.ExceptWith(exclude);
  hs.UnionWith(include);

  string result = string.Join(";", hs.OrderBy(item => item));
```

**Edit 2**: In case we want to deal with *duplicates* when excluding, e.g.

```
  string source = "1;2;3;3;3;3;7;8;9";

  // Remove just 2 of existing 3 
  // We should get "1;2;3;3;7;8;9";  
  int[] exclude = new int[] { 3, 3, 7 };
  int[] include = new int[] { 3, 6 };
```

I suggest `GroupBy` instead of `Where`:

```
  var seq = source
    .Split(';')
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))        // now we have IEnumerable<int>
    .GroupBy(item => item)                  // removing "exclude"
    .SelectMany(chunk => chunk
       .Skip(exclude.Count(item => item == chunk.Key)))
    .Concat(include)                        // appending "include"
    .OrderBy(item => item);

  string result = string.Join(";", seq);
```

Comment: Perhaps consider doing `.Except(exclude).Union(include)` instead in the middle there.

Comment: @Enigmativity: `Except` and `Union` remove *duplicates*. I'm not sure that we are working with *sets* (that's why I use `IEnumerable<T>`, `Where` and `Concat`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko If you use `HashSet<>`, couldn't you use directly `SortedSet<>`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - Good point. Do you think that a similar issue is in using `.Where(item => !exclude.Contains(item))`? A single item in `exclude` removes multiple items in the source.

Comment: @Enigmativity: yes, in the current implentation removes *all* `3, 6, 7`. In case we have `3, 3, 3, 4` and want to remove `3, 3` (only `2` occurence of `4`) I suggest `GroupBy`: `GroupBy(item => item).SelectMany(chunk => chunk.Skip(remove.Count(chunk.Count())))`